# Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$delete_posts with custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, capabilities

I created a custom post type called `gdpr_qao` and I set `'capability_type' => array( 'gdpr_qao', 'gdpr_qsaos' )` in register_post_type arguments. On main custom post type screen I get:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$delete_posts in
>   /srv/www/wp-plugins/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php
>   on line 411

and in bulk actions there isn't delete option.

How can I solve this problem?

Here the custom post type code:

```
public function register_gdpr_qao() {

    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Problemi & Pareri GDPR', 'post type general name', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Problema & Parere GDPR', 'post type singular name', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'menu_name'          => _x( 'Problemi & Pareri', 'admin menu', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Problemi & Pareri GDPR', 'add new on admin bar', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Aggiungi nuovo', 'quesito', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'add_new_item'       => __( 'Nuovo Problema & Parere', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'Nuovo P&P', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Modifica Problema & Parere', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'Visualizza P&P', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'Tutti i Problemi & Pareri', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Cerca P&P', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Genitori dei P&P:', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'Nessun Problema & Parere trovato.', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nessun Problema & Parere trovato nel Cestino.', 'ccwdpo' )
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'             => $labels,
        'description'        => __( 'Descrizione.', 'ccwdpo' ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'gdpr-qao' ),
        'capability_type'    => array( 'gdpr_qao', 'gdpr_qsaos' ),
        //'map_meta_cap'       => true,
        'has_archive'        => true,
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => 6,
        //'menu_icon'          => 'data:image/svg+xml;base64,',
        'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author' ),
        'taxonomies'         => array( 'gdpr_category', 'gpdr_area_of_interest' )
    );

    register_post_type( 'gdpr_qao', $args );

}
```

Comment: Some information from [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/30991) could be helpful.

Comment: I read that but I couldn't solve the problem, maybe I don't understand what is the possible solution indicated there (my English isn't so perfect ...)

Comment: Edit your above description and add your register_post_type code as well. I'll check

Comment: Edit done, thank you!

Comment: is the capability_type you set for single and plural correct?

Comment: "qao" stands for "question and opinion" so I choose "qsaos" for plural (questions and opinions), is it correct?
I create a custom role to manage post capabilities with:
`add_role(
   'gdpr_dpo',
   __( 'GDPR Data Protection Officer' ),
   array(
    'edit_gdpr_qao'             => true,
    'read_gdpr_qao'             => true,
    'delete_gdpr_qao'           => true,
    'edit_gdpr_qsaos'           => true,
    'edit_others_gdpr_qsaos'    => true,
    'publish_gdpr_qsaos'        => true,
    'read_private_gdpr_qsaos'   => true,
   )
  );`

Comment: I think you must select a capability that is already present like `post`. Your new role `gdpr_dpo` and the capability you have set doesn't seem to relate. Not sure what the capability is supposed to do there.

Comment: I need to create custom post type specific capabilities and I need to assign them to my custom role. It almost works but do I get that notice for $delete_posts?